# how to connect to a postgresql database using libre office base?

Tags: postgresql

I think it surpringly difficult to find some clarity on how to connect to a postgresql db using libre office base...

Is it one of the name in the drop down menu? Or do i need to install a plugin ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Had to install `sudo apt-get install libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql`

https://www.uzerp.com/blog/2019/05/06/libreoffice_postgres/